# Can't access machine localhost from docker on OSX

Tags: macos, docker, docker-for-mac

I have a docker build that works fully fine in Linux

E.g. there's a docker nginx container that proxies traffic from docker to the machine localhost, where running another service (nodejs app) on dedicated port

```
location /app {
    rewrite ^/app/(.*)$ /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://172.25.0.1:5555;
}
```

But when I run it on the OSX - I have a curl error

> cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 30003 milliseconds

Looks like docker machine can't access the port that listening on local machine

How can I resolve this?

Comment: how is macos linux? they may be both unix-based but they're not the same

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs The question is related for both of them, as it works on linux, but don't work on OSX, but probably you're right, will remove linux tag

Comment: Is the nodejs process also running in a docker container?

Comment: @zero298 no, nodejs process is running on mac, w/o Docker

Comment: Try `proxy_pass http://docker.for.mac.localhost:5555;`